# Docker Binding parse exception with testcontainers

Tags: java, windows, docker, testcontainers, docker-java

I would like to run some integrational tests which would include setting up a complete environment with org.testcontainers Docker Compose Module. I am new to Windows and Docker testing, same with the testcontainers.

Using versions:

- Docker desktop community: 2.5.0.0
- org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.0
- org.springframework.boot 2.3.4.

My code looks like the following:

```
@ClassRule
public static DockerComposeContainer environment = new DockerComposeContainer(
                    new File("C:\\dev\\myproject\\myapp\\docker-compose\\docker-compose.env.yml"),
                    new File("C:\\dev\\myproject\\myapp\\docker-compose\\docker-compose.yml"))
                    .withExposedService("myservice_1", 9999)
                    .withLocalCompose(true);
```

My compose files looks something likes this.

```
services:
  myservice:
    image: myapp/myservice:latest
    hostname: myservice
    volumes:
    - ../volumeDir:/app/volumeDir
    - ../config:/app/config
    expose:
    - 9999
    ports:
    - 9999:9999
    command: -Dspring.liquibase.enabled=true
    networks:
    - internet
```

It looks like some Binding error, the most significant part of the stacktrace:

```
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.testcontainers.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException:
> Cannot construct instance of `com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Binds`,
> problem: Error parsing Bind
> 'C:\dev\myproject\myapp\volumeDir:/app/volumeDir:rw'
>      at [Source: (org.testcontainers.shaded.okio.RealBufferedSource$1); line: 1,
> column: 1369] (through reference chain:
> com.github.dockerjava.api.command.InspectContainerResponse["HostConfig"]->com.github.dockerjava.api.model.HostConfig["Binds"])
>       at org.rnorth.ducttape.timeouts.Timeouts.callFuture(Timeouts.java:68)
>       at org.rnorth.ducttape.timeouts.Timeouts.doWithTimeout(Timeouts.java:60)
>       at org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.WaitAllStrategy.waitUntilReady(WaitAllStrategy.java:53)
>     ...
```

I have tried to change the path to absolute without any difference. Do you have any ideas what can make this bind unparseable?

Comment: Have you tried testing the compose file with docker-compose up -d ?

Comment: @Vitaly Chura Its working without the testcontainers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to a current issue with Testcontainers and the recent Docker for Windows version. They are [already aware of it](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3493) and a [fix seems close to being merged](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/3514).

**UPDATE**: Version [1.15.1](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/releases/tag/1.15.1) is now available that fixes this bug.